# Need to convert html to google doc native format using Java

Tags: google-drive-api

I've read through the API documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/ however I cannot find the answer to my question.  And attempts to google a solution have failed.

I have a series of previously uploaded small HTML files sitting in Google Drive.  What I want to do is write a short application to convert each of these to native Google Document format (mime type "application/vnd.google-apps.document").

I want to do this using Java code and not using GAS code.

The approach I used was to query drive for the File object corresponding to the item I want to convert.  Then I pull that file's content as a string.  Then I create a new file of mime type "application/vnd.google-apps.document" and upload it with the HTML content.  Not surprisingly it didn't work.

So then I tried a different approach:  Upload the content as "text/html" but set the "convert" flag to "true".  Well I didn't see any direct API to set the convert flag to true.  So I tried:

```
File oBody = new File() ;
oBody.setTitle ( sTitle ) ;
oBody.setDescription ( sDescription ) ;
oBody.setMimeType ( sMimeType ) ;
oBody.set("convert", bConvert);
```

This did not fail.  But it did not create a Google Document either.  It just created a text file identical to the original file.

How do I upload a document containing "text/html" content and get Google Drive to convert it automatically to a Google Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `convert` flag has to be set in the `files.insert` request and not the `File` resource.
Using the snippet in the `files.insert` documentation as reference, this is what you should do:

```
...
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setConvert(true).execute();
...
```

Comment: You've made me a happy man!  That worked beautifully!  Thankyou thankyou.

Comment: I tried the same for file update, but content seems to be corrupted  while viewing in web(google drive).